# How to write switch statements based on 3 variables?

Tags: java, permutation

I have a lecagy validator class that I'd like to work with. It gives all permutations to validate 1-3 different fields.

```
class Validator {
    Checker Validator.A, Validator.B, Validator.C;
    Checker[] ABC = {Validator.A, Validator.B, Validator.C};
    Checker[] AB = {Validator.A, Validator.B};
    Checker[] BC = {Validator.B, Validator.C};
    Checker[] AC = {Validator.A, Validator.C};
}
```

I don't have any influence on this class. But have to use one of these Checkers.

I want to chose the needed validator based on the fields that are not empty.
Therefore, I wrote the following switch statemend. But to me it seems to be very ugly. How could I improve this?

```
String a, b, c;
boolean isA = !a.isEmpty();
boolean isB = !b.isEmpty();
boolean isC = !c.isEmpty();

Checker[] checker;

if (isA && isB && isC) {
    checker = Validator.ABC;
} else if (isA && isB) {
    checker = Validator.AB;
} else if (isA && isC) {
    checker = Validator.AC;
} else if (isB && isC) {
    checker = Validator.BC;
} else if (isA) {
    checker = Validator.A;
} else if (isB) {
    checker = Validator.B;
} else if (isC) {
    checker = Validator.C;
}
```

Comment: I don't see a `switch` statement.

Comment: This is typically what a bitmask field is for, but since you claim you cannot change the `Validator` class you need as the output, I don't think you can do much better than this without a difficult to read hack.

Comment: What prevents you from dynamically creating an array of Checkers?

Comment: Very subjective question; this assumes that people answering would know what you find ugly and what you don't find ugly.

Comment: I suppose if you find yourself having to do this more than once, you could create a wrapper method that uses a bitmask and a utility method that converts from your bitmask to the `Validator` format (that utility method will look a lot like what you have above).

Comment: Shouln't it be `isA`, `isB`, `isC` in the if/else statements ?

Comment: Shouldn't you use variables `isA`, `isB` and `isC` in your `if` statements instead of `a`, `b` and `c`?

Comment: Pattern matching switch statements that are available in functional languages are very convenient for this kind of logic, here is an [example in Scala](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/case-classes-and-pattern-matching.html#i-174768992-1). Let's hope that's the next thing that trickles down into mainstream languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
List<Checker> checkers = new ArrayList<Checker>();
if (!a.isEmpty()) checkers.add(Validator.A);
if (!b.isEmpty()) checkers.add(Validator.B);
if (!c.isEmpty()) checkers.add(Validator.C);
Checker[] checker = checkers.toArray(new Checker[checkers.size()]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you could do it this way

```
    List<Checker> list = new ArrayList<>();
    if (!a.isEmpty()) {
        list.add(Validator.A);
    }
    if (!b.isEmpty()) {
        list.add(Validator.B);
    }
    if (!c.isEmpty()) {
        list.add(Validator.C);
    }
    Checker[] checker = list.toArray(new Checker[list.size()]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify it using reflection, approximately like this (haven't actually compiled, but should be close enough):

```
String name = (a? "A":"") + (b? "B":"") + (c? "C":"");
checker = Validator.class.getField(name).get();
```

Comment: ... and now you have two problems :-)

Comment: Truth be told, I can't think of any particular problem. It won't discover at compile time that the `Validator` fields have changed, that's the worst I can think of. And it meets the explicit requirement  to use the arrays in `Validator`. What if the contents of those arrays change? The other "good" methods mess up in that case.

Comment: My comment was semi-flippant, but reflective solutions to things do tend to be less efficient and more fragile than non-reflective ones.

Comment: The flippancy wasn't lost on me (and a possible paraphrase of my recent paraphrase :) I'm just less opposed to reflection, especially since there are full JVM languages where reflective calls are a part of the core syntax. Efficiency is an issue only with member lookup, which can be cached.

Answer (score 0):

if you **really** want to do it, you have to convert whole your input to "case'able" data. e.g int

```
2 ^((int) a) * 3^((int) b) * 5^((int) c)
```

or to string (since java 7)

but, don't do it. it's ugly. create a collection and fill it with necessary checkers. as showed by Chris King

Answer (score 0):

You can do the whole thing with `enum`s. It adds a powerful extendibility component.

```
enum Checker {
  A, B, C;

  public boolean check () {
    // You do this.
    return true;
  }
}

enum Validator{
  ABC(Checker.A, Checker.B, Checker.C),
  AB(Checker.A, Checker.B),
  BC(Checker.B, Checker.C),
  AC(Checker.A, Checker.C),
  A(Checker.A),
  B(Checker.B),
  C(Checker.C),
  ;
  final Checker[] checkers;
  Validator(Checker ... checkers) {
    this.checkers = checkers;
  }
  boolean validate(Collection a, Collection b, Collection c) {
    // Grow the name of the validator from the data.
    String name = (!a.isEmpty()?"A":"") +
            (!b.isEmpty()?"B":"") +
            (!c.isEmpty()?"C":"");
    // The final result.
    boolean checksOut = true;
    // TODO: Handle the all-empty scenario.
    if ( name.length() > 0 ) {
      // Pull the checks array out of the correct validator.
      Checker [] checks = Validator.valueOf(name).checkers;
      for ( Checker check : checks ) {
        // Do all of the checks defined.
        checksOut &= check.check();
      }
    }
    return checksOut;
  }
}
```